# Numeric cell values get appended with extra decimal digits in C# NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, xslt, npoi

While importing excel, few of the numeric cells value is read abnormally with appended digits after decimal. For Ex: 109.340000 is read as 109.34000000000003
But if I write same value in different cell in excel sheet it is read correctly as 109.340000. Also copy paste of same number results in similar issue 109.34000000000003. I have checked the format in excel they are same for both the cells(which is Number).

I know we can use Math.Round to fix this issue in code but I want to know why does excel reads differently in c# and if there is any hidden format in excel which leads to it?

Comment: In C# I would recommend the use of the `decimal` numeric datatype instead of the `double` type. Whether there is a similar type in Excel or a way to declare that you want to map the Number cell in Excel to a `decimal` value in POI/C# is something I don't know. But I think you are just seeing the limits of IEEE 64bit double floating point numbers.

Comment: @MartinHonnen While reading from excel, the sheet data itself reads it with appended value, before even parsing to decimal or double

Comment: Then it sounds more like Excel also uses IEEE 64bit doubles by default where unfortunately inaccuracies are known. Perhaps an Excel expert can help you to define/declare a more suitable, higher precision number type like the C#/.NET `decimal` for your cell.

Comment: Can you show us a sample sheet and some sample C# code? Which version of Excel is that, which version of NPOI? Does the Excel cell really contain a number with trailing zeros, like `109.340000`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen  The cells in the excel have Number format set as 6 decimal places, therefore trailing zero's appear in cell but not in formula bar. I have tried changing the excel precision and it worked fine for all the cells in code, no extra digits are added.